# The vector 0 is the only null vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

To prove the some set is vector space, I must prove 8 axioms. Two of then is the existence of the null vetor and the identity. May I have some vector diferent of 0 for the null vector, and some vector diferent of 1 for the identity?

Comment: $1$ is a scalar, not a vector.

Comment: The null vector and the identity are the same thing...the only internal operation is addition.

Comment: It sounds like there is some fundamental misunderstanding here.  Perhaps it would help if you explained the context in which you think you have found two different null vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two vectors $0_1$ and $0_2$, both fulfilling the axiom given in the definition of vector spaces (i.e. $0_1 + x = x + 0_1 = x$ and $0_2 + x = x + 0_2 = x$ for all vectors $x$ in the vector space). We would then have
$$
0_1 = 0_1+0_2 = 0_2
$$
so they are equal. In other words, no, you cannot have more than one null vector, becuase the very axiom that defines them also forces all of them to be the same.

Comment: I found a null vector (1,1), so may I say that the axiom is not satisfied?

Comment: Good answer. But I think it's fair to point out that you might have a vector space in whose underlying set there is an element called $0$ (for some reason) that is NOT the zero element of the vector space.

Comment: @Cosmocrazy If you have some strange vector addition operation on pairs of numbers such that $(1,1)$ fulfills the definition of a null vector, then that is your null vector. One such operation is $(a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (a+b-1, c+d-1)$, and is the result of moving the origin of your _coordinate system_, but not that of your vectors, down and to the left. If you were thinking of multiplying vectors together, so that $(a, b)(c, d) = (ac, bd)$, then that usually doesn't give a vector space, although it _could_ if you specify the right space and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @57Jimmy Well, I'll give you that it isn't _necessarily_ the zero element of the vector space. It _ought_ to be, though, if the naming makes any sense.

Comment: @Arthur I agree, but it's common for beginners' exercises to contain some confusing examples to see if the definitions are clear, and it seemed to me that it was the case for this question ;)